# Session lifetime of custom session variable

Tags: php, laravel

I have made a Laravel session variable. How do I set the timeout / lifetime of this?

I want to change the timeout of this session variable only.

```
Session::put('abc', $a);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can go to : .env or config/session.php
and change SESSION_LIFETIME 
OR
do like below:
Session::put('abc', $a , $LIFETIME);